# Loop not breaking when using user input

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Queue que = new Queue(50);

    System.out.println("Noki's Calculator");
    System.out.println("Choose an operation (*, /, +, -)");
    String inputOp = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println(" ");

    System.out.println("Now please enter your numbers. When finished, simply press enter.");
    boolean cont = true;
    while(true){
        System.out.print(" ::  ");
        String j = input.next();
        if(j != null) {
            int numb = Integer.parseInt(j);
            que.insert(numb);
        } else if (j==null) {
            input.close();
            break;
        }
    }

    que.view(); // PROBLEM: never executes this line

}
```

My code won't break out of the while loop, instead still asks for user input. When I press enter, it doesn't print "::" again, but never executes que.view()

Comment: then debug the code. ``j`` can never be ``null``. When you just press enter, ``j`` is ``""``.

Comment: Check your assumptions.  Fire up your debugger when the code fails to meet your expectations.

Comment: Please do not edit your question to an extent that invalidates all already given answers. Instead, post a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your implementation 'j' will never be null. When you hit enter "" will be assigned to j. You may need to change your logic as follows; Use input.nextLine() instead of input.next()

```
if(!(j.isEmpty())) {
    int numb = Integer.parseInt(j);
    que.insert(numb);
} else {
    input.close();
    break;
}
```

Comment: "j' will never be null" so why check if it is null, then?

Comment: I updated my code; the problem still persists. Is there something I can't catch?

Comment: @Ben Use input.nextLine() instead of input.next()

Comment: @ShehanCharuka Note that you can use `j.isEmpty()` instead of checking against `""` and the length.

Answer (score 2):

Use `nextLine()` instead of `next()` like below,

```
String j = input.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

`input.next()` does not return "null" when you just press "enter".

change

```
else if (j==null)
```

to

```
else if (j.equals(""))
```

Edit: this doesn't exactly answer the question but it has already been answered so i am leaving it as is.

Comment: You are right about `input.next()` never returning `null`. However, please pay attention that while having `if(j != null)` the `else if` will never be executed. Please, consider updating your answer.

Comment: I updated my code; the problem still persists. Is there something I can't catch?

Comment: @cs.spathis Note that there is also `String#isEmpty`. May be more readable.

Comment: @Poger You are right i should have read the question more carefully